# Primefaces withEclipse Helios, JSF 2.0 and jBoss 6 ClassNotFoundException thrown when deploying

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working on a web application **(EAR)** project using **eclipse IDE Helios, jBoss 6 AS, JSF 2.0**, when i installed the PrimeFaces library my projects cannot be deployed again and a ClassNotFoundException thrown.
I installed the PrimeFaces library by referencing the .jar (located in the WEB-INF/lib) in the web library, after some searchs on google i modified the web.xml according to [this topic](http://spring-java-ee.blogspot.com/2010/02/jsf-12-primefaces-web-application-with.html)

But the same problem appears, the PrimeFaces users guide is not free and i'm blocked at this problem. Thanx ...

Comment: Your link leads to an example for JSF 1.2 and Primefaces 1.x. If you use Primefaces 2.x, only the skin is configured in web.xml. Please post the part of your exception that makes clear which class cannot be found.

Comment: The exception message contains the answer (the name of the class which is missing in the classpath). If you don't understand it, please post the exception message if you want us to explain the answer.